# Simplest way to secure a NamedPipes WCF service?

Tags: .net, wcf, authorization, named-pipes

I'm using a WCF NamedPipesService to do IPC between two processes. Whats the simplest way to secure the WCF services so only my processes can access them?

I tried looking through the WCF documentation, but it all looks pretty complex, and seems to primarily focus on authenticating users rather than client processes.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/SV-SE/library/bb398990(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Securing the named pipe used by WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122741/securing-the-named-pipe-used-by-wcf)

Comment: @Jocke : it's not in english

Comment: That link is for securing hosted WCF web services, not apps via NamedPipes.

Answer (score 2):

Can't think of anything out of the box for named pipe binding. However there is always a workaround.

**Custom headers**

You can easily implement *IClientMessageInspector* interface to send some custom authentication info (process key word or login and password for example) with each service call. Then implement *IDispatchMessageInspector* to validate the headers on the service side. here you can find more about [message inspectors in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx).

**Windows authentication**
Just use a windos account no one can use except for your application and configure windows authentication like that

```
<security mode="Transport">
   <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
</security>
```

Personally I like the option with custom headers more but do you really need to authenticate you process at all? No one can access your service from public. Do you think there is somebody within your organization who can attack your service? I mean maybe it's not really the right binding in your case.

Comment: Here's a way to do the [custom header and validation](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1075) that is far more hacker-proof than a plain-text app.config file. It's also an easy example without having to do message `IClientMessageInspector`.